# Как вычленить определенные слова между тегами title?

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

**Пример текста:**

```
<title>Машины волосы мягкие и шелковистые потому что Маша пользуется Head & Shoulders</title>

Маша уже 10 лет пользуется Head & Shoulders и она очень довольна.

<!-- А это еще один title в конце документа -->

<title>Машины волосы мягкие и шелковистые потому что Маша пользуется Head & Shoulders</title>
```

Нужно регулярное выражение, которое найдет слова **Машины** и **Маша** между тегами title, при этом не производя поиск в остальном тексте.

Это нужно для дальнейшей замены слов:
`Машины` → `Олены`
`Маша` → `Оля`

Использую *PHP (PCRE)*.

Вот что получилось у меня:

`/(?<=<title>)(?:.*)(Машины|Маша)(?:.*)(?=<\/title>)/ui`

, но это регулярное выражение находит только слово **Маша**:

https://regex101.com/r/rN7pE3/2

Comment: найти и что с ними сделать?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, слова Маша и Машины в title потом нужно будет заменить, при этом не трогая остальной текст.

Comment: А простой заменой одной подстроки на другую без всяких регулярок - не?

Comment: @andreymal как вы замените одной подстрокой другую учитывая то, что замены должны производиться именно между тегами title?

Comment: Даже при этом можно найти способ ограничения области для замены (по крайней мере на python так всегда делаю, но наверняка и на php это не слишком трудно) (правда, код будет более раздут в сравнении с регуляркой, но не столь страшен, как сама рабочая регулярка :)

Answer (score 3):

В общем ничего умнее не смог придумать, если у кого-то есть варианты лучше, пишите.

```
<?php

$text = preg_replace_callback('/<title>([\s\S]*)<\/title>/iuU', 
    function ($matches) {
        return preg_replace(
            array(
                '/\bМашины\b/iu',
                '/\bМаша\b/iu'
            ), 
            array(
                'Олены',
                'Оля'
            ), 
            $matches[0]);
    }, 
    $text);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/(<title>)|(<\/title>)|(Маша)|(Машины)/ui', function( $match ) {
    static $title_state= 0;
    if($match[1]) {
        $title_state++;
        return $match[0];
    }
    if($match[2]) {
        $title_state--;
        return $match[0];
    }
    if($title_state<=0) return $match[0];
    if($match[3]) return "Оля";
    if($match[4]) return "Олины";
}, $text);
```

Comment: Это жесть, если честно, но зато если заменить 0 и 1 на инкремент и декремент, то можно обрабатывать рекурсивное вложение `<title><title></title>Маша</title>`

Comment: @ReinRaus Да, пожалуй стоит заменить

Answer (score 1):

Вот такая регулярка может найти всех Маш внутри всех тайтлов за один раз:

```
/(?<=<title>|(?!^)\G).*?\K(Машины|Маша)(?=(?:.(?!<title>))*?<\/title>)/gius
```

Можно сразу делать замену, т.к. `\K` обеспечивает, что все символы пред словом "Маша" не будут засчитаны даже в 0е совпадение (т.е. совпадение всей строки)

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/qU0xS2/1)

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в HTML тег `<title>` встречается только раз. Поэтому, может, искать первое появление подстроки "<title>", и закрывающего тега с помощью [`mb_stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-stripos.php); выделять подстроку между ними, и уже в полученным таким образом содержании тега `<title>` искать нужные слова регулярным выражением, или тем же поиском подстроки.

Comment: Такое решение не подойдет, т.к. в теории на странице тегов title может быть несколько, например один в начале, другой в конце и регулярку я собираюсь применять не только для title, но и для a и так далее.