# Регулярное выражение. Множественные совпадения и якоря

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

Имеется строка следующего вида:

```
a b c d [a b c Str1 d e f Str2 g h i Str3 ] e f g Str4 [Str5 a b c Str6 d] h i
```

Из неё необходимо выделить строки вида `Str\d+`. Но не все, а только те, что находятся внутри "якорей". В данном случае в качестве "якорей" выступают символы `[` (слева) и `]` (справа). То есть регулярное выражение должно найти строки

```
Str1, Str2, Str3, Str5, Str6
```

но пропустить `Str4`. Можно ли это сделать при помощи регулярных выражений? И если да, то как?

Comment: Этот вопрос поможет Вам? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489543/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-title

Comment: Или это. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448577/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: Если поймете как с помощью моего ответа по второй ссылке решить задачу, то я просто закрою вопрос как дубликат. Если не ясно, то напишите мне в комментарии: я адаптирую ответ для Вашего случая и закрою как дубликат.

Comment: @ReinRaus Первый решён без RegEx, второй что-то близкое. Спасибо. Пока не понял. Разбираюсь.

Comment: Хотя может и ответ Виктора Стрибижева в том вопросе Вам подойдет, если текст внутри "якорей" не должен обрабатываться как единая сущность.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489561/481 это и есть regex... Только используется callback для нахождения результата. Это и есть "каскадный спуск" по своей сути: вычленяем из текста бОльшую часть, а потом отдельно обрабатываем этот кусок текста.

Comment: _только те, что находятся внутри "якорей"._ -- якоря бывают вложенными? например: `[0[1[23]4[56]]8]`

Comment: @Stack, здесь вроде без разницы, т.к. если не внутри нижнего, то внутри верхнего якоря все равно будет находиться. Т.е. все равно "внутри якоря"

Comment: @Stack А вот ХЗ. Пусть не будет вложенных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наиболее простой способ решить данную задачу: применить метод "каскадный спуск".
Его суть невероятно проста:
Первым регулярным выражением вычленяем бОльший кусок текста. В данном случае это любой текст от `[` до `]`. Первое регулярное выражение будет таким:

```
/\[[^\]]*\]/s
```

то есть любой текст внутри `[...]`

К найденному тексту применим второе регулярное выражение, которое найдет искомый результат. В данном случае - это

```
/\bStr\d+\b/
```

Немного изменил выражение из вопроса, добавив границы слова, так как считаю это правильным ходом.

Итоговый код получится такой:

```
$text = "a b c d [a b c Str1 d e f Str2 g h i Str3 ] e f g Str4 [Str5 a b c Str6 d] h i";
$re1 = "/\\[[^\\]]*\\]/s";
$re2 = "/\\bStr\\d+\\b/";
preg_match_all( $re1, $text, $arr1 );
foreach ( $arr1[0] as $k=>$v ) {
    preg_match_all( $re2, $v, $arr2 );
    // обработка результата, например так:
    var_dump( $arr2[0] );
};
```

http://ideone.com/i1qqcr

Есть и другие способы решить задачу, но они не такие простые.
Крайне рекомендую "каскадный спуск", если Ваши познания в регулярных выражениях слабы.

---

Вариант 2.
Результат получается с "отрывом от контекста", то есть Вы не сможете обработать Str1-3 и Str5-6 как единое связное целое:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/448588/481

---

Вариант 3.
Результат с callback. Там используется replace, но мы то знаем, что в callback можно делать все что угодно, например обрабатывать полученные данные:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489561/481

---

Вариант 4.
Не будет работать в PHP, из-за использования неподдерживаемой функциональности:

```
(?<=\[[^\[\]]*\bStr\d+\b(?=[^\[\]]*\])
```

Comment: а где 4 вариант будет работать? я нигде не встречал, чтобы просмотр назад такое позволял (у вас, кстати, скобочка закрывающая пропущена). Если у любого закрывающего ""якоря" обязан быть открывающий, то убрав просмотр назад можно и на php этот результат получить ([пример](https://regex101.com/r/cF9wU7/2))

Comment: ВОРОН, пока поддержка есть только в языках семейства .NET, ну еще можно самому PCRE2 скомпилировать. kff, там ничего трудного, но не рекомендую это использовать в реальном коде, ведь такой код Вы сами не сможете поддерживать не изучив основательно перед этим регулярные выражения.

Comment: @kff А вы включайте режим /x и пишите многострочную регулярку с комментариями на подобии `/(?:  \[  |  # открывающая скобка или`  `(?!^) \G   # точка останова последнего поиска НЕ в начале строки` ну и т.д. тогда есть шаанс понять это даже через месяц :)

Comment: @BOPOH Ну это уже мелочи, косметическая правка решает проблему `(?:\[|(?!^)\G)[^]]*?(\bStr\d+\b)(?=[^\[\]]*\])`

Comment: @Mike, но это не решит проблему когда якори совпадают

Comment: @BOPOH Это я уже убрал из вопроса. Учитывая сложность RegEx с разными якорями, думаю, что одинаковые якоря заслуживают отдельного вопроса. К тому же это был уже чисто теоретический интерес. Но если народ считает, что я не прав - верну.

Comment: @kff в случае одинаковых якорей для практического результата можно не заморачиваться сложными регулярками. У Вас на страничке написан Python, приведу пример на нем для лаконичности: `"|".join( text.split("|")[1::2] )` В полученном тексте можно просто искать `Str\d+`

Comment: @ReinRaus Спасибо. Это отличное практичное решение!

Comment: @kff Но если все таки хотите сломать мозг, то я сделал регулярку на совпадающие якоря (якорь для наглядности `@`): https://regex101.com/r/jM5pQ5/1  `(?>(?:^[^@]+@)|(?!^)\G)(?(?=@)@[^@]*@|[^@])*?(\bStr\d+\b)(?=.*@)`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35778/discussion-on-answer-by-reinraus----).

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, похоже: `\[[\w\s]+(Str[\d]{1,})[\w\s]+\]`

Comment: Вот так https://regex101.com/r/fW4tZ6/1 ?

Comment: Нет. Только два совпадения. А надо пять.

Comment: Да, я тоже только что заметил =) сейчас поправим

Comment: Я прошу прощения, час ночи уже... не могу понять, почему он берет только последние Str... с утра посмотрю, на свежую голову