# Странное поведение жадного квантификатора

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В общем, имеется код регулярного выражения для парсинга атрибутов HTML тегов. Так вот, по какой-то причине не срабатывает отключение жадного поиска, я по разному пробовал ... Странная бесовщина творится, уже все волосы повыдергивал.

```
preg_match('~
<
 ([a-z0-9]+) #Получаем название тега
 \s*
 (?:[a-z_-]+="(.*?)")* #ВОТ здесь проблемное место! Этот кусок кода парсит все атрибуты
>
~xs', '<div id="test_id" class="test_clas">', $parts);

print_r($parts);
```

Нужно чтобы в массиве `$parts` находился список атрибутов, что-то вроде этого:

```
array(
'id' => 'test_id'
'class' => 'test_class'
)
```

То-есть, чтобы можно было получить отдельно название атрибута и его содержимое, а сейчас все атрибуты одной строчкой !!!

UPD:
Немного подправил код, изменил вот эту строчку: `(?:([a-z_-]+)="(.*?)"\s*)*` а именно, добавил вот этот кусочек `\s*`
Код работает как нужно, вот только находит самый последний атрибут, затирая первый. Как-то можно исправить сей недуг?

Comment: про HTML и regexp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Hit-or-miss, у вас не совсем верный подход. Первой регуляркой можно вычленить название тега и одной строкой все атрибуты в виде `id="test_id" class="test_clas"`, а затем второй регуляркой получить массив атрибутов и значений из этой строки.

Comment: Регулярка ищет окончание `">`, а оно есть только в конце последнего аттрибута. Поэтому `.*?`, пусть и лениво, но растягиваются до последней `"`, беря всё, что, казалось бы, нужно оставить.

Comment: Значение аттрибута может быть вообще без кавычек

Comment: Ошибку Вы нашли сами. Это хорошо. Вот ответ как захватить все атрибуты: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489760/481

Comment: Ошибку Вы нашли сами. Это хорошо. Вот ответ как захватить все атрибуты: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489760/481

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы с помощью `preg_match()` хотите найти неопределенное количество совпадений?

Вам нужно сначала найти тег, а уже потом искать в найденом неопределенное количество атрибутов с помощью `preg_match_all()`

А вообще, согласен с Sublihim. Для вашей задачи лучше подойдет html-пассер

Comment: Вопрос не "Что лучше использовать?", а "Чойта не работает?".

Comment: @Crantisz, думаете html-парсер работает по другому чем регулярки? :)

Comment: @Visman, там простые регулярки, уж точно не пытающиеся описать все конструкции разом.

Comment: Кстати, да, тоже задавался этим вопросом))) Как эти парсеры работают изнутри. Ну понятное дело, что эти модули в том же самом PHP уже скомпилированны и т.д. В общем да, я что-то погорячился, нужно было разделить регулярки на два этапа. Сейчас все робит)

Comment: @Visman HTML - может быть синтаксически некорректным, и тогда ваша регулярка встанет в тупик, в отличие от того же браузера. Но для вырожденных задач по поиску чего-то в html - можно и регулярки использовать, но корректно распарсить все случаи вам не удастся.